# Fixed numbers in a switch statement (Random)

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement, arc4random

I'm new to Xcode and i'm really stuck.

I have a         UIProgressView which fills up with a UISwipeGestureRecognizer. I also have a switch statement. Now I want that only 7 ways to run (from the 242) while     progressTrue is false. If     progressTrue is true, so the UIProgressView is on 1.0, it should select new 7 cases randomly. Is something like that possible?

Thanks for any help!

```
-(void)vorgangDev {

int number = arc4random() % 242;

switch (number)  {

    case 0:
        question.text = @"Anlieferung/anliefern";
        answer.text = @"delivery, supply/deliver, supply";
        answer.hidden = YES;
        break;
    case 1:
        question.text = @"Artikel";
        answer.text = @"article, item";
        answer.hidden = YES;
        break;
    case 2:
        question.text = @"Artikelanzahl";
        answer.text = @"number of articles/ ~items";
        answer.hidden = YES;
        break;

//And so on...
```

}

Here I call vorgangDev.

```
if (progressTrue.progress == 1.0) {
    // The UIProgressView is full
    // if this is true do the question. 

    CABasicAnimation* fade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
    fade.fromValue = (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    fade.toValue = (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:50/255.0f green:109/255.0f blue:43/255.0f     alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
    [fade setDuration:1];
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:fade forKey:@"fadeAnimation"];

    progressTrue.progress = 0.0;
    [self vorgangDev];
```

Comment: Put your data in an array. Then you can simply access the array using the random value. Do not hardcode all of that text in your code and do not use a `switch` statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already read. I am aware of my mistake! With this switch-statement it is not possible?

Comment: Even if it's possible, with a `switch` statement it is not advisable.